# SQL query to get all records based on a certain column value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I got the following table:

```
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
|  ID     | Data 1 |Customer | Alternative  |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
| 1       |1abc    | 1       |1             |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
| 2       |2abc    | 1       |1             |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
| 3       |ae12    | 1       |2             |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
| 4       |ad31    | 1       |2             |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
| ...     |...     | ...     |...           |
+---------+--------+---------+--------------+
```

I need the following information out of it:

1. How many different alternatives do exist --> to populate a HTML
   select box with its options.

Here we have 2 Alternatives. So I would populate my Select Box with Alternative 1 and Alternative 2.
Then, when the user picks one Alternative, I need to write all Records based on that alternative inside an JSON Array.

**For example:**

User picks alternative 1

```
[1;1abc;1;1],[2;2abc;1;1]
```

Or User picks alternative 2

```
[3;ae12;1;2],[4;ad31;1;2]
```

I tried

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Alternative from $table)
```

But this returns only 1 and 2 but not the whole records.

Comment: you are selecting only alternative so it gives the values for alternative

Comment: Why not just use SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY Alternative, then in your loop, you test if yout Alternative value is the same or not of the previous one.

Comment: ^ do not do that. This sort of filtering should be done in mysql NOT unnecessarily looping through more data than you need to in order to test the results in PHP.

Comment: sorry for being unclear at first. i edited the question to get more precise.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with a single query. Use two queries. One for fetching distinct alternatives and one for fetching options for each alternative.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Alternative FROM $table");
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    $alt = $row['Alternative'];
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Alternative = '$alt'");
    while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $res2 ) ) {
        //put your HTML here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a fairly easy way.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(alternative), id, data_1, customer 
          FROM table"
$result_set = mysql_query($query,$connection);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result_set);
```

You can also add a WHERE clause to the query if youre only looking for alternatives to a specific id, customer, or data_1.

Comment: This will not work ..it will simply fetch the all values from the table. Not according to the alternative

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of the output required; you can use the below query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  "[", ID,  ";", Data,  ";",  "Customer",  ";", Alternative,  "]" ) 
FROM test
GROUP BY alternative
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the alternatives, so use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Alternative) as NumAlternatives
FROM $table;
```